# Solution for a mobile main page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

What is the best approach if I want 6 icons full screen with jQuery Mobile on mobile and tablet view (regardless of the viewport)?

For example:
<>
|ICON 1 | ICON 2|
|ICON 3 | ICON 4|
|ICON 5 | ICON 6|
<>

I saw a lot of examples, but when I run the app in phonegap takes less then the full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQM grid with 2 columns and 3 rows:

```
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/256/256/sports/1/" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/256/256/sports/2/" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/256/256/sports/3/" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/256/256/sports/4/" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-a"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/256/256/sports/5/" /></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/256/256/sports/6/" /></div>
    </div>
```

In CSS make sure the grid is set to 100% height and each row cell is set 33.3% height.

```
.ui-grid-a {
    height: 100%
}
.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b {
    height: 33.3%;
    padding: 4px;
}
.ui-block-a img, .ui-block-b img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}
```

For the 100% height to work, you need to scale the content div to the device, see this article:  http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/content-div-height-fill-page-height/

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/WnD2y/)**

Comment: Just one think that I find really weird. On refresh, the page looks bad, when I resize it takes the style and is applied to have the full width. How can I fix that?

Comment: make sure and call the scaling function inside $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {}); So everytime a page is shown, it is scaled appropriately.